# Jquery - settimeout

Tags: jquery, settimeout

I have a jquery function that i need to delay 1 second.
I've searched here, and I need to use the settimeout function which I have no idea how to put in the jquery.

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.animacao').addClass("hidden").viewportChecker({
        classToAdd: 'visible animated fadeInDown', // Class to add to the elements when they are visible
        offset: 100    
       });   
});            
</script>
```

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: Are you trying to add a delay to the class that gets added everytime the element appears in the viewport? If so, that would have to be done by modifying the plugin.

Comment: Have you googled how to use SetTimeout?  This page has some examples http://www.sitepoint.com/settimeout-example/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the code you want to delay in the `setTimeout`

```
setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery('.animacao').addClass("hidden").viewportChecker({
        classToAdd: 'visible animated fadeInDown', // Class to add to the elements when they are visible
        offset: 100    
    });   
}, 1000); //the delay is set in milliseconds... 1000ms = 1 second
```